# My Java code for my project is not compiling, I don't see the error

Tags: java

The question is:
Create a new project called EvenOrOdd containing a class called `Tester`. In the `main` Method of `Tester` print a prompt that says, "Enter an integer:" Input the user's response from the keyboard, test the integer to see if it is even or odd (use the modulus operator % to do this), and then print the results as show below (Several runs are shown)

Enter an integer: 28 
The integer 28 is even.

Enter an integer: 2049 
The integer 2049 is odd.

Enter an integer: -236 
The integer 236 is even.

The code that I wrote it is correct to the question?

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*; 
public class HelloWorld{
Scanner kbReader =new(System.in) 
System.out.println("Enter an integer:"); 

    int kbReader.nextInt( ); 
    int inputNum; 
    if(inputNum != 0 || inputNum != 1) 
    { 
       inputNum = inputNum -1; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
      if(inputNum == 0) 
      { 
        System.out.println("Even."); 
      } 
    else if(inputNum == 1) 
    { 
       System.out.println("Odd."); 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Place your statements in a `main` method.

Comment: Any time you ask a question about code that isn't compiling, you should state the error in the question. Just like any time you've got an exception, you should include the details of the exception (and the stack trace) in the question.

Comment: When you've got it compiling, you'll need to look at this condition, by the way: `inputNum != 0 || inputNum != 1`. *Every* number is either not equal to 0 or not equal to 1.

Comment: With proper indentation it would be much easier to spot that you have mismatched `{` and `}`

Answer (score -1):

Here is some code which meets the specifications

- class is named Tester
- code in the main method
- use modulus operator %

Code:

```
import java.util.scanner;

public class Tester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int number = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(String.format("The integer %d is %s.", number, number % 2 == 0 ? "even" : "odd"));
}
```